# Problems with making the root prim filter the child prims by name, than change only the child prims with a certen name. Help please

Tags: linden-scripting-language

I need some help. I am working a script that will listen to a channel, take the message and use it as a texture command (this part i have), than change only the child prims that have the right name (this part i can not figure out). I know it is possible to do, but for the life of me i can not figure out how to filter by name than send the texture to the right child prim. Any help or ideas would be wonderful, Thank you. 
ps, if a list is needed, i will need help with that too, i cant seem to wrap my brain around them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [llGetNumberOfPrims](http://lslwiki.net/lslwiki/wakka.php?wakka=llGetNumberOfPrims) to find out how many prims there are in the object (if you don't know that already) and then use [llGetLinkName](http://lslwiki.net/lslwiki/wakka.php?wakka=llGetLinkName) on each of them in for loop to check the child prim name.

Answer (score 1):

```
set_textures(string name, string texture, integer side) {
    integer i;
    if(llGetLinkNumber() != 0)
        for(i = 0; i < llGetNumberOfPrims(); ++i)
            if(llGetLinkName(i+1) == name)
                llSetLinkTexture(i+1, texture, side);
}
```